# Confusing about a very simple program

Tags: parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have this question :

[image]

The program is very simple :

```
sub(b, a) 

<=>

sub(x, y) 
x = x + y = 3 + 2 = 5 
y = x + y = 5 + 2 = 7 

<=> 
b = 5
a = 7
```

therefore **d** is the right answer

but the given answer is **c**(a = 7, b =3 )

Why? What am i missing here ?

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "the parameter `x` is called by value, and the parameter `y` is called by reference".

So `b` is passed by *value*, which means that the `x` inside `sub` is just a local variable - it's not pointing to the same location as `b`.

Therefore, the changes made to `x` inside `sub` do not affect the variable `b` that was passed in.

Contrast with `y` which is passed by *reference*, which means that `y` and `a` are actually the same variable, so changes to `y` inside `sub` are reflected in `a` outside of it.

Comment: ahhhh, my bad my bad !!!!!! never learned to read the question carefully ! Thanks mate, i'll mark it as answer

Comment: No problem, it was a sneaky one!

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. As the prompt notes `x` is passed (or "called") by value. This means that when you pass `b` to `sub` as `x`, `x` contains only the literal value of `b`. What this means from a practical standpoint is that any changes made to `x` in `sub` will **NOT** affect `b` back in the main program.

On the other hand, since `y` is passed by reference, when you pass `a` to `sub` as `y`, `y` is really a **reference** to the variable `a` (`y` "points" to `a`). This means that if you make changes to `y` in `sub` **those changes affect** `a` **back in the main program.**

If the above is confusing to you, think of it this way: if a variable is passed by value to a function, you can replace the parameter name (`x`) with the **value** of the argument (`3`). If a variable is passed by reference to a function, you can think of it as replacing the parameter name (`y`) with the **variable name** of the argument (`a`).

With that in mind, let's revisit the question:

```
a = 2;
b = 3;

sub(b, a);

----------

x = x + y
```

(in this line `x` represents the **value** of `b`, which is `3`, so the value of `x` (but not `b`) is now `5`)

```
y = x + y
```

(in this line `y` represents the **actual variable** `a`, whose value is 3. When we add `x` to `y`, however, it **actually changes** `a`. Therefore, the value of both `y` and `a` after this line is 7)
    return;

So as you can see, `b` cannot be changed in the original function, so its final value can only be `3`. `a` however can be changed, and due to operations in `sub` now has a value of `7`.

I hope this clears up any confusion you were facing with this problem.

Comment: Thanks alot Alex, i knew about parameters passing stuff, i did not see the sneaky line of the question, don't know why, so careless of me, anyway thanks !